# Delimiting ng-repeat items by expression

Tags: angularjs

I need to delimit list of posts sorted by created_at. Something like this:

```
today
----delimiter----
earlier posts
```

Also i have many filters, my ng-repeat list looks like:

```
<li ng-repeat='post in posts | filter1 | filter2 | orderBy:'created_at':true'>
  {{ post.title }}
</li>
```

I can't access previous post to compare by using `posts[$index-1]`, because it will be not filtered collection. How can i access correct collection or are there any ways to realize that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="post in filtered = (posts | filter1 | filter2)"  ...
```

This will create an on the fly filtered list that you can reference with `filtered[$index-1]`